# triplets with points in big number

Tags: javascript, regex

In Python I can do this:

```
import re
s = '123123123123'
re.sub(r"(?<=.)(?=(?:...)+$)", ",", s )
123,123,123,123
```

How to make the same in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No Lookbehinds in JavaScript**

The question is interesting because JS has no lookbehinds. But we can do it like this:

```
replaced = yourString.replace(/(?!^)(?=(?:...)+$)/g, ",");
```

**Explanation**

- The `(?!^)` negative lookahead is the trick to replace your lookbehind. It asserts that what follows is not the beginning of the string. And at the beginning of the string, which is a zero-width position, that fails (think of it as 0+0=0)
- As you know, your `(?=(?:...)+$` matches a position that is followed by three characters x one or more times then the end of the string, ensuring the insertion of the comma in the right spot.

Comment: zx81, any chance you could run through what this means?

Comment: @Andy, with pleasure—just added explanation. :)

Comment: @Andy You're welcome, mate. The `(?!^`) is interesting, as the natural idea would be `(?<!^)` which of course is not possible in JS. :)

Comment: How can I prevent triplets after float's dot? E.g. my float is 820469710077.8724. Your example give me this: `82,046,971,007,7.8,724`.

Comment: Mmm that's a new question. :) I exactly answered the question you asked by translating your Python regex: `How to make the same in JavaScript?`, which has the same behavior on the float. I may have time to look at another question although it's getting late here. Please see next comment.

Comment: @zx81, I can accept your answer only after a hour, because somebody else could answer me, you know? This is how SO works...

Comment: No worries mate, you are under no obligation to accept any answer, ever. :) I was only explaining that I exactly answered the question. The new question is not good to address in the comments, we might have have another 15 comments to talk about details. Questions are free to ask and IMO it's cleaner to keep them separate.